# Use Content Security Policy scipt-src sha feature with Apache HTTP Server

Tags: javascript, apache, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm using Apache 2.4 and I'm trying to implement Content Security Policy.
I have set the following header in my **httpd.conf**

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default 'none'; script-src 'self'"
```

Now, I have inline javascript code using **script** tag inside html, as

```
<script>alert('Do something here')</script>
```

Note that script tag contains meaningful JS code, not this alert stuff I have put for sample purposes.

Now, Content Security Policy blocks such inline scripts. One way to whitelist these is to compute **SHA** hash for the aforementioned script and explicitly pass it in header as

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default 'none'; script-src 'self' sha256-dhfds73748=="
```

This allows the script to run.

Now I can generate SHAs for these type of scripts at build time using grunt.

But do I have to manually set these inside Apache **httpd.conf** as I make changes to these scripts and then manually restart my Apache HTTP Server?

Can I set this value at runtime inside Apache config?

Please note that I don't want to move the such code to a separate js file
and then call it via `<script src="path/to/my/file.js"></script>` unless it is the only way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this for static html or is this a web application? If it's a web application, a dynamic policy is fairly easy. It it's a static site using some sort of templating (e.g. Jekyll) you can use the csp meta tags to easily update a policy.

If neither is true above, I'll have to defer to those with specific Apache experience. I don't think managing meta tags over many static pages is a good approach.

Comment: I'm using single page web application architecture

Comment: The meta tag is probably the way to go then. At least in your development environment.

Comment: Oh cool! I didn't know you could set Content Security Policy headers in meta tag directly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It has some limitations on which CSP features can be used but I can never remember what they are.

Comment: I only need to set it dynamically for script-src and style-src. Rest attributes remain same always and  can be managed fairly via Apache only. Thanks.