# Adding Content Security Policy to Azure Web APP

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to add a HSTS and X-XSS to my Web App. I have been testing using this:
https://securityheaders.io

I have been using this link as a starting reference:

https://tomssl.com/2016/06/30/how-to-fix-the-http-response-headers-on-azure-web-apps-to-get-an-a-plus-on-securityheaders-io/

I add web.config file inside /site/wwwroot , i stop and start my web app , but it's look no effect ( i think that web.config is Not required )

I have Linux web app (Slack : NodeJS)

How would I accomplish this ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `Content-Security-Policy` in your code. It's the better way to solve your issure.

**Related Blog**.  [How To Secure Node.js Applications with a Content Security Policy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-node-js-applications-with-a-content-security-policy)

[image]

*I found that in azure linux, it is not directly known which webserver is used in the linux server, so I did not try the following method. If you are interested, you can raise a support for help, let Microsoft Engineer help you.*

As you use linux platform, so you need to determine which webserver you use in your web app.

1. If use apache, you can add .htaccess file to solve the issue.

   [Implement Content Security Policy using local htaccess file (Apache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273726/implement-content-security-policy-using-local-htaccess-file-apache)
2. If nginx, you can add yourcustom.conf file to do that.

   https://gist.github.com/plentz/6737338

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but how i can determine which webserver ? i don't think IIS or Apcahe ( i try with web.config and .htaccess , but no effect ). also Nginx is not used in Azure Web APP

Comment: @QuentinMerlin IIS is for windows.

Comment: @QuentinMerlin As I said I don't recommand you use add .htaccess or .conf files to do that. Change your code is best way!

Answer (score 0):

Found this while trying to resolve the same problem. Azure static web apps now has a staticwebapp.config.json file where these headers can be specified. I put the file in the root app_location of the deployment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration